# My Grandfathers Patent - D94036

Tags: usd94036

In 1934, My Grandfather (kurt Loesch) received a patent for an atomizer cap (D94036).

The information I've found states that the patent was assigned to Lentheric - which was sold to another company, then sold to another company, and on and on. The company is now Shaneel Enterprises LTD.

It appears that this patent had a term 14 years from 1934.

My questions are:
1.  Does the 'assignor' still hold the rights to this patent? Have those rights been transferred to each company since 1934?
2.  The term of the patent was 14 years.  What happens/ed after the term of the patent expired?
3.  Do I (sole remaining family member) have rights to this patent (patent royalties)

Thank you!
Susan Loesch
sloesch@gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

I haven't looked this specific patent up but once a patent expires, and the state of limitations on past infringement passes (long long ago), there are no rights at all. In any case, if a patent is assigned outright by the inventor to a company, the company, not the inventor or his heirs has the rights. Copyrights have a "revert to the author" provision after a certain time. Patents do not.